# SoX on 64-bit Windows - how to chose output device

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card

I have created 3 virtual sound devices using VAC and now i want to start 3 sox instances and make every instance use a separate sound device for output when playing a wav file.

Command `sox.exe file.wav -d` plays the file to the default sound device. How do i force it to use a different sound device ?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sox d:\AUDIO\02.wav -t waveaudio 0
```

Comment: Might help to explain what these things are? What's the -t arguement? How do you decide what to put in the bits that go "wavetable 0" ? A fuller answer would be appreciated here

Answer (score 2):

Copied from [here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html)

> waveaudio (optional)
>
> MS-Windows native audio device driver. Examples:
>
> ```
>  sox infile −t waveaudio
>  sox infile −t waveaudio default
>  sox infile −t waveaudio 1
>  sox infile −t waveaudio "High Definition Audio Device ("
> ```
>
> If the device name is omitted, -1, or default, then you get the
>   ‘Microsoft Wave Mapper’ device. Wave Mapper means ‘use the system
>   default audio devices’. You can control what ‘default’ means via the
>   OS Control Panel.
>
> If the device name given is some other number, you get that audio
>   device by index; so recording with device name 0 would get the first
>   input device (perhaps the microphone), 1 would get the second (perhaps
>   line in), etc. Playback using 0 will get the first output device
>   (usually the only audio device).
>
> If the device name given is something other than a number, SoX tries
>   to match it (maximum 31 characters) against the names of the available
>   devices.
>
> See also play(1), rec(1), and sox(1) −d.

I am not entirely certain where to view the list of devices, but I suspect in Windows 10 it's the list under `Settings > Sound > Manage Sound Devices` .

The device "Stereo Mix" seems to work for me, and it's listed on that screen. This records the "Stereo Mix" input to a file:

```
sox -t waveaudio "Stereo Mix" out.wav
```

Also note that you can run `sox --help` and it will list the available audio drivers. For me, that's only `waveaudio`, but maybe there are others. Idk.

Comment: With SoX 14.4.2 on Windows 10, calling the CLI with debug log level yielded a list of possible devices to choose from: `sox -V6 -n -t waveaudio non-existent-device`